# Curious about the differing limits of integration when solving an ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This is one of those things that I just haven't thought about but always used. It came up when I was looking over this old problem to solve $x′′+ϕ(x)=0$ with IC $x(0)=x0>0$ and $x′(0)=0$. But even solving the most straight forward ODE involves integrating both sides to different limits, and that is I just decided, after years of use, seems strange.

So for the problem that made me stop and think about it, we let $y=x′$ to form a system and have $dy/dx=−ϕ(x)/y→ydy=−ϕ(x)dx$. And here is where I feel like some details are missing that I am unsure about. We integrate this equation to get:

$.5y2=−∫_0^xϕ(z)dz+C$

So the LHS was integrated from 0 to y and the RHS from 0 to x. But why should I expect that these will be equal when y need not equal x? I'm a bit chagrined that I never stopped to think about such a basic aspect of ODEs. I suspect there is an easy explanation. Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually integrating both sides of the   equation $y{dy\over dx}=-\phi(x)$ with respect to $x$ over an interval $[0,t]$, say.

That is, you write  $$\int_0^t y{dy\over dx}\,dx=\int_0^t -\phi(x)\,dx.$$  The substitution $u=y$ in the integral on the left hand side of the above then transforms the equation  to 
$$\int_{y(0)}^{y(t)} u\,du =\int_0^t -\phi(x)\,dx. $$  This gives the same equation as what you have (with $t$ used as the independent variable, rather than $x$). In the end the  "shortcut"  method you describe works.

Note in your example, you have $y(0)=0$.  In general, the limits of integration  are determined from the initial conditions . On the "$x$-side", from $x_0$ to $x$; on the "$y$-side", from $y(x_0)$ to $y$.

Comment: Thanks, that clears that up!